# Vuejs cannot filter data array in method

Tags: arrays, vue.js, methods, filtering

I am using VueJS and trying to filter an array dynamically in an event handling function
My code like this:

```
data () {
    return {
      currentUser: '',
      abstractText: '',
      identifierList: [],
      title: '',
      selectedIDType: 'None',
      colorPalete: [{'identifierType': 'CellLine', 'color': '#FD0100'},
        {'identifierType': 'ChemicalEntity', 'color': '#F76915'},
        {'identifierType': 'DiseaseOrPhenotypicFeature', 'color': '#EEDE04'},
        {'identifierType': 'GeneOrGeneProduct', 'color': '#A0D636'},
        {'identifierType': 'OrganismTaxon', 'color': '#2FA236'},
        {'identifierType': 'SequenceVariant', 'color': '#333ED4'} ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    annotate (identifier) {
      var userSelection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
      var newNode = document.createElement('span')
      var palete = this.colorPalete.filter(function (p) { return p.identifierType === 'CellLine' })
      console.log(palete.color)
      newNode.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'background-color: ' + palete.color + '; display: inline;'
      )
      userSelection.surroundContents(newNode)
    }
  },
```

> Unluckily, the console.log(palete.color) always return 'undefined'

I saw that many people likely to add the filter function into computed: part, however this approach make my code larger and I wish to keep it inside the method

May I ask is the root caused by the data items are not able to filter in method?
Thank you

Comment: It's undefined because `palete` is an array of objects.  There is no property `color` on the Array itself, you must first access one of the objects, e.g. `palete[0].color`.

Comment: You can use the find() method instead of filter()

Comment: Thank you friends, that is my bad. Both of your ideas are work for me.